# jquery - show/hide checkboxes based on selected radio button

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am currently developing a small form for an order process.

The form has multiple fields, including input fields and radio/checkboxes.

The current form is as follows:

```
    <form id="order_process" name="order_process" method="post" action="">
    <table>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <label for="colour">Colour</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="small">Small</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="Small" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="colours" value="red" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="colours" value="blue" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="colours" value="yellow" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="medium">Medium</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="Medium" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="colours" value="orange" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="colours" value="blue" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="colours" value="green" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="large">Large</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="Large" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="colours" value="black" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="colours" value="white" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="colours" value="red" />
      </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </form>
```

What I need to do, is only show the `colours` checkboxes if i select a particular radio button. So these checkboxes need to be hidden on page load and only display based on the radio selected.

I know I can achieve this using jQuery, but I'm not sure how I'd do it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First have the rows containing the checkboxes hidden and all you need thereafter is this:

```
var lastRow = null;

$(":radio[name='type']").click(function(){
    if (lastRow != null){
       lastRow.toggle();
    }
    lastRow = $(this).parent().next();
    lastRow.toggle();
});
```

This will show the row of checkboxes associated to it. It will also hide any previously open rows for a different radio button that had been clicked.

You can try it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jXrxW/

Comment: That works well!! But when I click on let's say `Small`, then `Medium` the `Small` checkboxes still show. I'd like them to be hidden and only show the checkboxes relating to the radio, If possible? Thanks

Comment: No problem -- this will mean that <tr> containing all the checkboxes must come directly after the <tr> containing the radio buttons. If you end up changing your table design the code will need to be edited.

The way it works, as im sure you see is it take the radio button -- $(this), accesses it's parent -- $(this).parent() which is the <tr>, and fines the next one -- $(this).parent().next(), giving you the <tr> containing the checkboxes. If you use this approach, make sure you properly adjust this instruction to match your design flow.

Good luck :) Click answered if it helps:)

Comment: My only problem now, is that I have 2 more radio buttons below and when I select them, the field is hidden again. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean radio buttons that aren't part of the color group?

Comment: Yes. This is an order form, so I'd like it when I select a colour, then select a `delivery method`, then `colours` are still shown. Thank you

Comment: Oh okay -- change the $(":radio") to $(":radio[name='type']).click(..

http://jsfiddle.net/jXrxW/1/

Comment: ye yee :) and as you probably notice, that is referencing your radio buttons by selecting those with their name attribute set to 'type'

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this with jQuery, but the essence is that you should hide all the checkboxes (`$('input type["checkbox"]')`) in `$(document).ready`, and then bind `click` events to the radio buttons (`$('input type["radio"]')`), which show the relevant items. You could make this easy by adding rel values to the checkboxes to indicate which radio button should show them.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to add classes to your checkboxes, like this :

```
<td>
    <label for="small">Small</label>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="Small" />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="Small" name="colours" value="red" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="Small" name="colours" value="blue" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="Small" name="colours" value="yellow" />
</td>
```

And then, add a `change()` listener on your radio buttons, and `show()` the corresponding checkboxes :

```
$(":input[name=type]").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("input[type=checkbox]:not(." + value + ")").hide();
    $("input[type=checkbox]." + value).show();
});
```

[**jsFiddle example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/w4VCv/1/)

Comment: The event onChange won't work for radio buttons. Better is the onClick event.

Comment: OP -- if you think you may need to reorganize your design in a way that my method based off positioning ceases to work I would suggest this approach using identifiers instead of positions.